# Extend typography in Material UI theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is this possible to define extra fonts (font-family) in Material UI theme. I would like to get something like this:

```
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
        fontFamily: '"Open Sans", sans-serif',
        fontFamilyPrimary: '"Lato", sans-serif',
        fontFamilySecondary: '"Nunito", sans-serif',
    },
});
```

Comment: How do you want to use these additional font families? Do you want to map them to particular Typography variants (e.g. have `variant="subtitle1"` always use `fontFamilyPrimary`) or do you just want to be able to leverage them in custom components?

Comment: @RyanCogswell just want to be able to leverage them in custom components. For example like this: `const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({ root: { fontFamily: theme.typography.fontFamilyPrimary, } }));`

Comment: Did you encounter some problem when trying to do this?

Comment: Yes I tried. When I defined fontFamilyPrimary then I get an error: `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'fontFamilyPrimary' does not exist in type 'TypographyOptions | ((palette: Palette) => TypographyOptions)'.`

Comment: I don’t use TypeScript myself, so I can’t help much with that. If you use `any` to get past the TypeScript error, does it work fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had to do the same. The solution is to augment the createTypography module definition and add what you need.

```
declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createTypography' {
  interface FontStyle {
    fontFamilySecondary: string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Based on @Luke Chapman's* answer.
In MUI v5 this is how to do it.

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles/createTypography' {
  interface FontStyle {
    font1: string; // custom prop that you need goes here
  }
}
```